# Disable an AutoPlugin from the sbt command line

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm using a Scalariform AutoPlugin and would like to disable it when running tests on the CI server. Is there a sbt option to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to achieve this is via an environment variable. Please note in my example Code below I use the sbt-release plugin but it should be easily adoptable to scalariform.

```
lazy val isJenkins = sys.props.get("JENKINS").isDefined

lazy val disPlugins = if(isJenkins) Seq(ReleasePlugin) else Seq.empty

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).disablePlugins(disPlugins:_*)
```

The first val checks if we the system property `JENKINS` is set. Depending on this value we add the ReleasePlugin to the Sequence of Plugins that need to be disabled. And finally during our project definition we actually disable those.

If you start sbt with the jenkins property set (`sbt -DJENKINS=true`) the ReleasePlugin is disabled

Comment: +1 for a valid solution, but if I had to decide between my CI server needlessly formatting my sources vs. cluttering my build definition like this, I'd rather have the CI do the formatting :(

Comment: You could create a custom project function which does exactly this and put it into a helper Object, than at least your build.sbt would still be clean